# Google cloud function non persistent disk

Tags: google-cloud-functions

What is the Google Cloud Function non-persistent disk space (/tmp directory) size that a cloud function receives on creation ?

For example on AWS you get 500MB.

Answer (score 1):

`/tmp` directory is mounted in the RAM of Cloud Functions, therefore the maximum capacity of this directory will vary depending on the size of your function as a whole.

Do note that the exact amount of RAM doesn't mean the exact amount of files you can store, as your app is also loaded in the RAM. For your reference, the [maximum memory per function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits) is 8192 MiB.